# 99 Chevy Lumina heavy oil leak from engine passenger side

Tags: chevrolet, oil-leak, lumina

[image: Shows passenger side of engine from below, with serpentine crank and tensioner, showing the highest point I have found oil]

Lots of oil dripping from the passenger side of the engine.  Best I can tell, the highest point I can see wet oil is near the pivot for the serpentine tensioner, but I also see oil a bit forward of that, near some bolts and what looks like a sensor (the orange arrow on the right side of my picture).  Above the crank pully (I think) it looks dry / no oil.

Any ideas for common leak culprits in this area?

A few more pictures:
[image: A few more angles showing the highest point oil is visible]

Comment: I'd be checking the usual culprit for a leak high on the engine which is a leaking valve cover gasket.  Beyond that, you're just going to have to start taking parts off until you can find the source of the leak.  I'm not able to see much from your photos other than this car is a rusty mess.

Comment: Another common culprit is the main engine seal at the crank. Oil can be thrown with the pulley to higher spots. You can purchase florescent oil dye. Clean as much of the existing oil off the engine as you can. Then put in the dye. Drive for awhile and using a blacklight you can trace the leak to its source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks all!  It turns out I'm dumb, it's transmission fluid leaking from a line going to the oil cooler and then splashing everywhere.  Cheers!